# Euler's Method in Python giving RuntimeError

Tags: python, recursion, differential-equations

I have to write code to perform Euler's Method of approximation for my diffeq class for a step-size of .5 and .1. When it is .5 my code runs fine and provides the approximation. However when it is almost anything less than .5, I get

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

And if I try to increase the recursion depth, I eventually get `Segmentation fault: 11`.

Here is the code. Please help me figure out why I am getting a recursion error, or how to improve the code so there is less recursion.

```
import sys
from pylab import *
h=.4
t=0
dep=[]
ind=[]
def sqr(q):
    return q*q
def d(x,t):
    return x+sqr(t)-2
while t<=3:
    def x(t):
        if t==0:
            return 1
        else:
            return x(t-h)+h*d(x(t-h),t)
    dep.append(x(t))
    ind.append(t)
    t+=h
plot(ind,dep,'o')
t=arange(0,3,.01)
x=exp(t)-t*(t+2)
plot(t,x,)
title("Euler's Method for dx/dt=x+t^2-2")
xlabel('t')
ylabel('x')
show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stop condition `if t==0` is too specific, so unless at some point the iteration hits **exactly** `0`, the recursion won't stop.

Instead catch `t==0` **and below**, with `t<=0`:

```
while t<=3:
    def x(t):
        if t<=0:
            return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming from floating point rounding errors.  If you run it through the debugger at one point t = 1.1110223 e-16, which does not equal 0, so it starts running into the negative numbers infinitely.

I changed the comparison to

```
if t < 0.001:
```

and the program converges towards a value of t of 3.0

On a less important note, declare your x(t): function *outside* of the loop as it adds extra overhead, and make your else statement

```
delta = x(t-h)
return delta + h*d(delta, t)
```

so that it doesn't run the recurse loop twice for each number.

Comment: Why, <0.001, and not <0?  Doesn't 0.001 just add an error into the calculation, or am I missing something?  It seems that it's really the "<" that's important here.

Comment: <0 would change the meaning of the code- mine triggers the break on the iteration that it is approximately 0, yours breaks it on the next iteration.  Of course, I don't know the algorithm, so I could be wrong about the intent.

Comment: I changed the t condition and it runs for smaller h now. Thank you!

Comment: @Paul: if you're trying to break the iteration on the step before the zero crossing, it would be better to break at the zero crossing and then look back one stop.  0.001 is too arbitrary, and unless you have a reason this will break where you want it to for every input, it would be better to solve this in a more robust way.

Comment: The iteration will always go to 0 if you do it by hand... the problem comes from float rounding.  There is probably a better way to write if x ~ 0... but for this specific algorithm, this will accomplish the goal.  BTW Zeke, if the answer works for you, it wouldn't hurt to accept it